# How can i design a current follower that can copy current without affecting the circuit current?

Tags: current, converter, buffer

I want to design a circuit which will copy a current from another circuit without affecting that circuit current.
 An input circuit there is some current through a resistor or path I want to follow that current and will output through a load (load resistance may independent). How to design that circuit.
please help.
Thanks.

[image]

I want to replace R4 as it is the load and **not grounded(floating load)**. I need this circuit which will copy the current which is though R4 path and can output the same current with grounded load.

Comment: Add a 50mV current sense resistor and a differential Op Amp that senses mirror current, with buffer as required??  What swing and BW?

Comment: Sir please elaborate i am new in electronics, I am unable to understand this short note. Would you please expain? Thanks you.

Comment: what is your circuit and which current it in to you want to copy?

Comment: This smells like an XY problem such as trying to make motor currents equal in order to drive a bot in a straight line when in fact this does not work. Explain the problem to be solved and not how what you think you need to solve it.

Comment: Sir please have a look I edit the question. If you have any query ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to replace R4 as it is the load and not grounded(floating
>   load). I need this circuit which will copy the current which is though
>   R4 path and can output the same current with grounded load.

If your load needs to be grounded then consider this using a PNP transistor and an op-amp like this: -

[image]

R1 is the current sense resistor and you need to choose an op-amp that works with its inputs at the positive voltage supply rail. Still there is one further issue and that is the input voltage; in the diagram above it is referenced to the positive rail and it's more convenient to have it referenced to ground so a further circuit is needed: -

[image]

The circuit above uses MOSFETs and not BJTs but the principle is the same. The right hand part of the circuit is what I have shown in the first diagram and the left part of the circuit converts the positive power rail referenced input signal to a ground referenced signal using a similar (but much lower power) current generator.

pictures taken from [my answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/268462/help-with-trying-to-understand-voltage-controlled-current-sources) to a previous question on stack exchange.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way of going about this is to follow a current to voltage converter with a voltage to current converter.

You'll choose what type of converter to use in each place depending on your other constraints, like are the currents floating or ground referenced, and are they always unipolar, or above some minimum current, or full bipolar including zero?

In the most constrained but simplest case, with unipolar currents that don't go to zero, that are referenced to the same rail, you could use some form of current mirror, where the current to voltage converter is simply a resistor and a transistor connected as a diode.

In the least constrained case you would need a sense resistor and a differential amplifier followed by a Howland current source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQcpYR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the left, the current mirror only deals with currents with respect to the positive rail. You can change that to ground or the -ve rail by replacing PNP transistors with NPN. This is a basic 1:1 current mirror, you can get scaling with a ratio of the resistors, and a better output impedance with additional cascode transistors.

On the right, a floating current is converted to a voltage by a differential amplifier. I've wimped out of drawing the [Howland current pump](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa474a/snoa474a.pdf) though it's about the same complexity as the differential amplifier. Note that there's also a modified Howland, which has much better output current capability. While the Howland is differential input, the output will affect the input conditions, and so the differential amplifier is needed as a buffer in the most general case.

Of course you can mix and match simpler first and second converters, according to your particular input and output constraints.

Comment: Sir it is ok but most expensive for the sence i want to add this with my circuit is also too complecated, Is there any simple solution.

Comment: @TechReboot give some specifications for the current range at the input, and the output, and then we can think about what the simplest circuit is that can do the job. Without those specifications, only the most complicated topology will do. With those specifications, we can simplify it down to something that is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to design a circuit which will copy a current from another circuit without affecting that circuit current.

This is not possible.  Refer back to basic physics.  Any means of measuring a current will have some effect on that current or the circuit producing the current.

You therefore can't proceed according to your requirements.  Go home or make the requirements more realistic.  You also need to specify where this input current is flowing.  Is one end connected to ground? To power? What current range? How accurate must the output current be?

Real engineering starts with specs.  It's OK to iterate and update the specs according to realities you find along the way, but you have to start at least with what you are given that you have no control over.

Comment: Sir sorry that my question is not understandable for you. Sir I want to make a 1-5v to 4-20 mA voltage to current converter and this circuit work like as I expected with i/v = 4 conversation ratio. All good but the load r4 is not grounded load it is floating load so if i use this with other circuit then it should be load independent and grounded too, as because ground is the common terminal of all circuit. So i want to design a few little more to copy the current through 250 ohm or r4 in the grounder load configuration.

Comment: I hope you will understand what i want to say, is not ask me where i need to elaborate.