# Switching different loads without voltage drop

Tags: batteries, switches

I want to switch different loads on my battery (V1 & R1). R1 is internal resistance of the battery. THe battery is a cr2032.

The reason i want to switch different loads is because i want to calculate the internal resistance of the battery under different loads. The problem i am facing is that when i switch the 10ohm battery on, the drain source voltage over M1 is relative high. This means that the voltage on the ADC pin is not its correct value.

Basicly i want to switch the 3 resistors, but without a voltage drop over the mosfet. I have thought of relay's, but i like to avoid mechanical switched because the period of measuring is very short (around 50 ms) and relays have bouncing contacts. I am looking for a good mosfet but i cannot find it. (small RDSon, logic level, no large IDS current rating)

Does anyone have ideas or alternatives?

[image]

Comment: [Shopping question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: What's supplying M1 gate voltage? Use an independent supply for this to get the full 10V gate drive; then (if need be) upgrade the transistor to one with Rds(on)@10V < 1% of 10R.

Answer (score 0):

Forget it. Make rather a current sink with known and programmable load current and see how much the voltage drops.

Make a web search "voltage controlled current sink" You'll get several versions. Start from this EESE story: [Help with trying to understand Voltage controlled current sources](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/268462/help-with-trying-to-understand-voltage-controlled-current-sources)

You can control it with DAC or PWM+Lowpass-filter from a computer. If you use PWM have also one I/O bit for fast force to zero. It has a transistor which shorts the low-pass filter output or otherwise makes the current=0 with no waiting the decay of the filtered control voltage.

The DAC can be external - a set of resistors connected with analog switches, no voltage drop problems, the resistors can be much bigger than the Ron of the switches.

If it must be switched load resistors for some invisible reason calculate or read from a prepared look-up table the correction which takes into the account the no-load voltage, the loaded voltage, which fets are ON and the measured properties of the fets.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What exactly is a programmable current sink? I have never heard of this before. You got a site with some info and how it will apply in this project?

Comment: The answer has more.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a good mosfet but i cannot find it. (small RDSon, logic level, no large IDS current rating)

You can try IRLML2502. Max Rdson 0.080ohm @ Vgs = 2.5V. [Datasheet](http://infineon.com/dgdl/irlml2502pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535668048e2606).

Answer (score 0):

You say, "the drain source voltage over M1 is relative high", but, what is relatively high?

Have you tried bipolar transistors. The BF337-40 has a VCE(sat) max of 0.7 V but, this is measured at a current of 500mA. In your circuit the current is less than 128mA and for a random BC337-40 in the configuration below I measured a VCE(sat) of 0.13 V.

Is this larger or smaller than the FET version you are using?

[image]

Comment: .13V voltage loss is to high. i want to ninimize it to max 10mV